# Integration of docusign and generate the access token c#

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am working on integrating Docusign Authorization Code Grant Authentication.  I was getting docusign login site html code as my return so then I realized this needs to run in the browser. I ran the URL and got to the docusign login page and after logging in I can get the code in the redirect url. But my concern is how I can do this with C# code.

I had tried this with sdk as well but still i got the HTML of Docusign login page in response.
I am using the below url to generate the code.

Comment: I don't know the specifics for docusign, but in general authentication tokens typically get transmitted in the _headers_ of an HTTP request / response, not in the _body_ (where you find the HTML of the page, for isntance)

Answer (score 0):

[Auth Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant) requires that you use a web browser to authenticate and then redirect the call to your web server with a code. You can then exchange this code for an access token and that can be done from any app.

If you need a non-web app to make API calls you need to use [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/). JWT allows you to obtain the access token without any web UI. You do need to obtain consent at least once (via web UI) but that doesn't have to be done in the context of your app (assuming again you're building a non-web app).